# Y-Axis values in Pandas interpolation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, interpolation

I have a dataset consisting of 'N' number of features/variables. One of these columns has missing values which I would like to interpolate. The interpolate() method of Pandas helps in doing so. The input for this method is the name of the column with missing values that needs to be interpolated, that's all.

```
df["Column_4"].interpolate(method='linear')
```

In case of linear interpolation, a straight line is fit through the data points. Before doing so, how are the data points plotted in the graph? I understand the 'x-axis' contains the specified column values. What values are taken on the 'y-axis'?

Comment: Did you read the doc (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html)? If you only use the column with a linear interpolation it will ignore the index and treat the values as equally spaced, so it will construct a dummy index to use for your interpolation. There is no graph involved.

Comment: There will be an x-axis & y-axis in the feature space right? I was referring to this as a graph. And if dummy 'index' values are considered for each data point, won't we end up looking at a straight vertical line of data points instead of a scattered sea of data points?

Comment: You can provide your own index and then use `method=index` or `values` to interpolate using your own x values.

Answer (score 1):

it is based on axis. So if you want to use specified column, setup your axis first:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html

```python
# df - pandas dataframe
# y_column_name - position values
# x_column_name - column with values where NaN will be interpolated
df = df.sort_values(by=[y_column_name])  # if you need to sort your data
df = df.set_axis(df[y_column_name], axis=0)
df[x_column_name] = df[x_column_name].interpolate(method='index', axis=0)
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)  # Reset the index of the DataFrame to the original index
```